# redirect every other page to amp version except home page -nginx

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx

I am trying to redirect all my mobile users to the amp version of the website except for the home page which dont have a amp version.Every other amp page has '/amp' prefixed to the page uri path.
Below is my nginx config

```
if ($mobile_rewrite = perform) {
  rewrite ^(?!.*(/|/amp)) http://www.example.com/amp$request_uri? permanent;
  break;
}
```

My intention is to redirect any route to amp version except for the home page.
Redirection rule should be as:

> www.example.com   --->  www.example.com
>
> www.example.com/hollywood  ---> www.example.com/amp/hollywood
>
> www.example.com/article/abc  ---> www.example.com/amp/article/abc

Comment: It looks like you need `^(?!/?$)` - to match all but empty or `/` input that goes to the regex engine.

Comment: ok. I am not really good with regex. how do i exclude both '/amp' and '/'. otherwise i get too many redirects.

Comment: If `amp` should also be "excluded", perhaps, you need to use `^(?!(?:/?$|(?:.*/)?amp(?:/|$)))`

Comment: Note that regex itself either matches a string or not, it does not allow/exclude/whatever. Nginx will redirect or not based on that match or no match. So, what input should be matched?

Comment: Every page accept the home page should be redirected to amp page.I need to put '/amp' along with home page in regex ignore list other wise nginx will keep rewriting infinite times resulting "too many redirects".
All pages except 'home page' and  'amp' pages should be matched and allowed

Comment: So, the regex above  - `^(?!(?:/?$|(?:.*/)?amp(?:/|$)))` - should work for you. See [what it matches](https://regex101.com/r/EsE6Ge/1).

Comment: Thanks a lot,its working.may i know how to add more exceptions like ignoring .js and .css files.could you explain the expression probably as an answer to this question so that i can accept it and would be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?!/?$|(?:.*/)?amp(?:/|$))
```

See [here what kind of input it matches](https://regex101.com/r/EsE6Ge/2).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!(?:/?$|(?:.*/)?amp(?:/|$)))` - the negative lookahead that fails the match if the lookahead pattern matches:

  - `/?$|(?:.*/)?amp(?:/|$)` - either of the 2 alternatives:

    - `/?$` - an optional (1 or 0 occurrences of) `/` and then end of string `$`
    - `|` - or
    - `(?:.*/)?amp(?:/|$)` - an optional sequence of any 0+ chars up to the last `/` (see `(?:.*/)?`), followed with `amp` that is followed with `/` or end of string.

To add a condition to avoid matching `js` or `css` files, add an alternative:

```
^(?!/?$|(?:.*/)?amp(?:/|$)|.*\.(?:js|css))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```